# Combine three values into one in a MVC dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to combine the values FirstName + LastName + Email into a single value for my dropdownlist in a MVC application using linq2sql.

The code I'm using now, that works for only one output value in the list, is:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("SaleEmployeeId", new SelectList(ViewData["SaleEmployees"] as IEnumerable, "Id", "FirstName", Model.SaleEmployeeId), "-- Choose --", new { @class = "required" })%>
```

But I want to combine "FirstName + LastName + Email" where "FirstName" has its place in my dropdownlist.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this (in your controller):

```
var values = _userRepository.FindAllUsers().Select(u => new { ID = u.UserName, Name = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName + " " + u.EmailAddress});
var userDropDown = new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name");
```

Then put `userDropDown` in the viewbag/viewdata, and read it in your view.

Comment: that will work and fills the dropdownlist in my view. But i use a EditorTemplate with viewmodel. So when i try to fill SaleEmployees with userDropDown i get the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: What happens if you put the following code in your view: `<%= Html.DropDownList("SaleEmployeeId", ViewData["userDropDown"] as SelectList) %>`

Comment: Yes that worked fine when i wanted to create a new post. But if I want to edit a post? I then want the value when i created the post to be auto-selected.

Comment: i solved it by setting the SaleEmployeeId in:

var userDropDown = new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name" SaleEmployeeId);